# VBA Looping through a Collection

Tags: vba, loops, collections, autocad

I have a collection of files that I selected in the SelectManyFiles function and I want to run multiple private subs on each Drawing in the collection function. Here's my code:

```
Sub Main()

Dim Drawing As Object
Dim Drawings As Collection
Set Drawings = SelectManyFiles()

For Each Drawing In Drawings
    'Call multiple private subs to run on each drawing
Next Drawing
End Sub
```

I think there's something wrong with the loop but not sure exactly! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you do or don't know whether this works? Do you have any other code that you've tried and know doesn't work?

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me the error of Object required.

Comment: what's the type of "Drawings"? the "Collection" class is enumerable?

Comment: They are AutoCAD .dwgs and yes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The collection that's returned by SelectManyFiles is not returning a collection of objects. It's probably returning a collection of Strings, but that's just a guess. Change your sub to this

```
Sub Main()

Dim Drawing As Variant
Dim Drawings As Collection
Set Drawings = SelectManyFiles()

For Each Drawing In Drawings
    Debug.Print TypeName(Drawing)
Next Drawing
End Sub
```

And see what the Debug.Print gives you. If it's any scalar (string, long, double, Boolean, etc), then you need to declare `Drawing` as Variant. Only if all of the collection items are objects can you use Object.

Answer (score 2):

TRY

```
    FOR X = 1 TO DRAWING.COUNT
        'STUFF HAPPENS
    NEXT X
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.